# Can I cash my son's cheques?

Tags: canada, check

My son got a cheque from the Canadian government, but he lost his ID. Instead of taking the cheque to Money Mart which charges a lot of money when they cash cheques, he signed it over to me, I signed it, and I gave him his money. Could I get into trouble for this? If the bank thinks this is wrong, can they put a hold on previous cheques I cashed for him?

Answer (score 2):

I am not Canadian, but I am posting this as an answer rather than a comment so it can be downvoted as necessary.

Strictly speaking, you aren't cashing your son's cheques. You are cashing the cheques that he has signed over to you: they are *your* cheques at that point. I think the only wrinkle would be if your son wasn't allowed to sign the check over to a third party in the first place, though I can't imagine why that would be the case.

Comment: In the US, IRS refund checks cannot be cashed over the counter or endorsed to someone else. Perhaps refund cheques from Canada Revenue have similar restrictions.